# AMFPHP + Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, amfphp

I'm developing a Facebook APP with AMFPHP. I got the AMFPHP working, and the Facebook SDK, my problem is that when I call a service through AMFPHP gateway to access a service that will connect to FB and return the UID, for example, I get a null value. My guess is that I'm doing something wrong connect the AMFPHP service to the FB platform.

This is the gateway.php

```
<?php

define("PRODUCTION_SERVER", false);

include "libraries/amfphp/globals.php";
include "libraries/amfphp/core/amf/app/Gateway.php";

$gateway = new Gateway();

$gateway->setClassPath("./services");
$gateway->setClassMappingsPath("./services/vo");

$gateway->setCharsetHandler("utf8_decode", "ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-1");
$gateway->setErrorHandling(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if(PRODUCTION_SERVER)
{
    $gateway->disableDebug();
    $gateway->disableStandalonePlayer();
}

$gateway->enableGzipCompression(25*1024);
$gateway->service();

?>
```

and this is the test service:

```
<?php

require_once("../libraries/facebook.php");

class Test
{
    public function uid()
    {
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
          'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          'cookie' => false,
        ));

        $session = $facebook->getSession();
        return $facebook->getUser();
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what I might be doing wrong?

PS: I skipped the login and permission verification in the service class, assuming that the user is logged in and have the necessary permission.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would like to retrieve the user information of the user who calls the AMF service, but the problem is that when you instantiate the Facebook SDK class with your appId and appSecret, there is no user logged in, you just had your application connected to Facebook. If you want to maintain a Facebook user session in your application, you have to implement Facebook connect in your web app, which will enable you to retrieve a Facebook session, then you can use that session to make request to Facebook on behalf of the user. You can read more about it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login).